# Ajax post json response issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an issue with ajax response. I am using custom query for fetch result from database. Json response always shows null value while query is running successfully. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST)){

$arr = array();
//$query = mysql_query(" insert into login (user,pass) values ('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."') ") or die('test');

$query = mysql_query(" select * from  login where user = '".$_POST['firstname']."' && pass = '".$_POST['pass']."' ") or die('test');
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        if($fetch)
        {
                $_SESSION['ID']= $fetch['id'];
                $arr['id'] = $_SESSION['ID'];

        }
        else
        {
            $arr['failed']= "Login Failed try again....";

        }

}

echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

Comment: Is it php? If it's the case it would be nice to mention it and add such a tag

Comment: What is the sense of `if($fetch)` after `while($fetch)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query);

Comment: You mean `$arr['id']` is always `null`?

Comment: response shown always null but  "$arr['id']"  having a value .

Comment: `print_r($arr)` to check if it is empty.

Comment: it is working fine when i hit this link in url . But issue with ajax response always shown as null.

Comment: May be you do POST in ajax but use $_GET for your $query params?

Comment: now i updated my full page code please check....

Comment: can you show how you are making the ajax request

Comment: request making in json format like :  json_encode($arr);

Comment: Can you post your ajax code ? with complete jquery as we get idea how you are sending and picking the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amandhiman i did not get what is the use of if statement with in the while

```
if($fetch)
    {
            $_SESSION['ID']= $fetch['id'];
            $arr['id'] = $_SESSION['ID'];

    }
```

the mention code definitely works for you

```
    if($rows>0)
    {
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
             $_SESSION['ID']= $fetch['id'];
             $arr['id'] = $_SESSION['ID'];
        }
    }else
        {
            $arr['failed']= "Login Failed try again....";

        }
```

Comment: @ sandeep great going it is working fine for me.. thanks a lot  you save my day

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code, (**mysql is deprected**), working for me with my test database table (Debug it, `var_dump $result,  $result->fetch_assoc(), $result->num_rows`)

```
    <?php

    $servername = "localhsot";
    $username = "yourser";
    $password = "passyour";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

   if(isset($_POST)){ 

    $arr = array();

    $query = "select * from  login where user = '".$_POST['firstname']."' && pass = '".$_POST['pass']."' ";

    $result = $conn->query($query);

    $rows = $result->num_rows;

        while($fetch = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {

            if($fetch)
            {
                    $_SESSION['ID']= $fetch['id'];
                    $arr['id'] = $_SESSION['ID'];

            }
            else
            {
                $arr['failed']= "Login Failed try again....";

            }

    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

Comment: session_start();
$username = "root";
$password = "ubc@ubc";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("blog",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select examples");

Comment: Replace your mysql with mysqli, modify your code mysql is deprecated

Comment: Working for me , with my test table

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(isset($_POST)){

    $arr = array();
    //$query = mysql_query(" insert into login (user,pass) values ('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."') ") or die('test');

    $query = mysql_query(" select * from  login where user = '".$_POST['firstname']."' && pass = '".$_POST['pass']."' ") or die('test');
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($rows>0)
        {
            while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                 $_SESSION['ID']= $fetch['id'];
                 $arr['id'] = $_SESSION['ID'];
            }
        }else
            {
                $arr['failed']= "Login Failed try again....";

            }

    echo json_encode($arr);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all **start session** before playing with it on the top of page

> session_start();

**check your database connectivity.**

Use **print_r($arr)** for testing your array();

Answer (score 0):

first off all you are using session variable . to use session variable you need to initialize it by `session_start()`

you are using key in the array in this way it will return the last inserted record in the array . try this code

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhsot";
    $username = "yourser";
    $password = "passyour";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

   if(isset($_POST)){ 

    $arr = array();

    $query = "select * from  login where user = '".$_POST['firstname']."' && pass = '".$_POST['pass']."' ";

    $result = $conn->query($query);

    $rows = $result->num_rows;

        while($fetch = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {

            if($fetch)
            {
                    // if wants to use session then start session 
                    session_start();  // else it will return null
                    $_SESSION['ID']= $fetch['id'];   // i don't know why this ??

                   // $arr['id'] = $_SESSION['ID'];   comment this 
                    $arr[] = array('msg'=>'succsee','ID'=>$fetch['id']);

            }
            else
            {
                $arr[]= array('msg'=>'fail','ID'=>null);

            }

    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```